# Why does django call __init__() twice for form fields

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to use [django-simple-autocomplete](https://github.com/praekelt/django-simple-autocomplete) in a form. However, when I add debug prints to the `simple_autocomplete.widgets`, I see that for each form field's *widget*'s `__init__()` is called twice, first with the parameters supplied in the form specification and a *second* time without **any** arguments, which obviously breaks everything that excpects a parameter.

I have to work around this by doing something like following:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['foo'] = AutoCompleteWidget(url="/json_url")

    foo = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        widget=None,
        ....
        )
```

Why on earth is this so?

**EDIT / CLARIFICATION**:

- this happens if I **don't** have the above workaround, but instead just have the widget=MyWidget() in the foo definition.
- it's the **widget**'s `__init__()` that is called twice.
- @zubair89 - I do have the `def __init__()` - that's how I actually found out that it is called twice!

Comment: I'd be more curious why it's being called twice than implementing workarounds

Comment: try: def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

Comment: Init method is called when a new instance of a model is being created. So you are probably creating more than one objects of your model in your view.

Comment: @dado_eyad the physical location of `def __init__` in the class body means nothing. If it's present, it will get called immediately after `def __new__`

Comment: @Kimvais can you show us your view in which you are making object of this form class..