# Python class methods always get executed twice

Tags: python, class, methods, tkinter

I'm new to Python and ran into a problem where methods in the class `Gui` always get executed twice.

Here is the gui class which inherits from `Tkinter`:

```
from Tkinter import *

class Gui (Tk):
    def createKdWindow(self):
        print("createKdWindow has been triggered")

    def activate(self):
        print ("activate has been triggered")
        self.tk.mainloop()
```

and here is where the methods get called from (**init**.py):

```
from pm_test.gui import Gui

datgui = Gui()
datgui.createKdWindow()
datgui.activate()
```

When I run my program, I get the following console output:

```
createKdWindow has been triggered
activate has been triggered
createKdWindow has been triggered
activate has been triggered
```

So my methods were executed twice. I don't know where this is coming from. Does anybody know how to solve this?

**Fixed:**
Putting the code from **init**.py into a new module fixed this issue!

Comment: I had a similarly bizarre incident once, but on completely unrelated libraries. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898218/why-does-django-call-init-twice-for-form-fields - that code got rewritten (or at least heavily refactored), but I never found out what really was the issue. I _think_ I was running Python 2.6.6 - is this the case for you as well?

Comment: I tried running that code verbatim on Python 2.7.3, and can't reproduce the problem. What Python version are you using?

Comment: I tested it with Python3.2.3. There is no such issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I´m running Python 2.7.4

Comment: I can't reproduce this on python2.7.3 (I put it all in one file).  If you put it all in one file, does the problem go away?

Comment: I'm curious when the extras get triggered... Maybe put some print statements between each of your lines to check when the extra call is made.

Comment: I just tried this under 2.7.4 with `Tkinter.__version__` revision 81008, and also couldn't reproduce, so I think I can tentatively rule out some obscure 2.7.3/2.7.4 issue.

Comment: so I put it in one file and now it works. But that´s not really what I want.

Comment: Perhaps your pm_test package contains an `__init__.py` script which contains some redundant code? Or perhaps the PYTHONPATH is picking up a different version of pm_test.gui?

Comment: Does your `pm_test.gui` file contain test code outside the class? If so, this may be getting executed in the import. Put it in an `if __name__ == "__main__"` to avoid that.

Comment: @FredLarson There is actually just one import outside the class as I posted above

Comment: Could you please include the whole `pm_test.gui` file?

Comment: That´s actually the whole file. What I found out so far is that everything in __init__.py (the module where I call the class methods) will be executed twice. It doesn´t matter which function I call (eg print). When I create a new module and simply copy&paste the code from the __init__.py it´s the same.

Comment: It actually happens because of the import of pm_test.gui

Comment: I don´t know why but somehow it works now by putting the code from __init__.py into another module. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @kidul Could you post your solution as an answer and accept it? It could be useful if someone has a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed: Putting the code from init.py into a new module fixed this issue!